# MainCore使用メモリサイズを768KBより大きいメモリサイズに設定するとエラーが出る

Tags: spresense, arduino

Spresense Arduino v2.0.0にて、メインコアアプリケーションが使用するメモリサイズをArduino IDEメニューから変更できるようになる拡張機能が追加されていました。実際に動作確認を行ってみましたが、768KBより大きいメモリサイズを指定するとエラーが発生します。以下実際の実行手順です。

1.「ツール」→「ボード」→「ボードマネージャ」
　"Spresense Reference Board"のバージョンを2.0.0に更新。
　
　　
2.「ツール」→「ボード」　　　　"Spresense"を選択
　「ツール」→「書き込み装置」　"Spresense Firmware Updater"を選択
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　ブートローダの書き込み実行。
　
　
3.Lチカサンプルを書き込み。

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(LED0, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
    delay(1000);

    digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
```

「ツール」→「memory」　
　　・"640KB"　　　→　　点灯確認
　　・"768KB"　　　→　　点灯確認
　　・"896KB以降"　→　　エラー

以下、896KB設定時の実際のエラーです。

```
up_hardfault: PANIC!!! Hard fault: 40000000
up_assert: Assertion failed at file:armv7-m/up_hardfault.c line: 148 task: AppBringUp
up_registerdump: R0: 0012d9c0 0d032638 0d0277f4 0d15fff8 0d0324a8 00000190 0d0276e0 0d01fe53
up_registerdump: R8: 00000064 00002000 00000000 00000000 00000001 0d02d1c0 0d00e2e9 0d00e316
up_registerdump: xPSR: 01000000 BASEPRI: 000000e0 CONTROL: 00000000
up_registerdump: EXC_RETURN: ffffffe9
up_dumpstate: sp:     0d024fa8
up_dumpstate: IRQ stack:
up_dumpstate:   base: 0d025000
up_dumpstate:   size: 00000800
up_dumpstate:   used: 00000148
up_stackdump: 0d024fa0: 000007e4 0d00295f 000000e0 00000000 00000000 00000001 0d02d1c0 0d00e2e9
up_stackdump: 0d024fc0: 0d00e316 0d024fd0 0d002b83 00000003 00000000 0d002b8b 0d002b69 0d00c83b
up_stackdump: 0d024fe0: 000000e0 0d00962d 000000e0 0d02d0ec 00000190 0d0276e0 0d01fe53 0d002b1b
up_dumpstate: sp:     0d02d1c0
up_dumpstate: User stack:
up_dumpstate:   base: 0d02d230
up_dumpstate:   size: 000007e4
up_dumpstate:   used: 00000288
up_stackdump: 0d02d1c0: 00000000 00000180 00000000 0d00e56b 00002000 00000000 00000000 0d004705
up_stackdump: 0d02d1e0: 0d01fe53 00000000 00000064 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
up_stackdump: 0d02d200: 00000000 0d0047a3 0d00043d 00000000 00000000 0d004165 00000000 0d02d234
up_stackdump: 0d02d220: 00000101 0d004b0b 00000000 00000000 deadbeef 0d02d23c 00000000 42707041
up_taskdump: Idle Task: PID=0 Stack Used=0 of 0
up_taskdump: hpwork: PID=1 Stack Used=576 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=2 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=3 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=4 Stack Used=352 of 2028
up_taskdump: AppBringUp: PID=5 Stack Used=648 of 2020
up_taskdump: cxd56_pm_task: PID=6 Stack Used=352 of 996
up_taskdump: <pthread>: PID=7 Stack Used=312 of 1020
```

Spresense recovery tool等を使って工場出荷時状態にリセットをする等
　試してみましたが解決には至っていません。ご存知の方いらしたら
　ご教授願いたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご指摘いただいた問題を修正したパッケージを先ほどリリース致しました。
ボードマネージャよりv2.0.1のパッケージへアップデートしてお試しください。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: アップデート後、無事にメモリサイズ768KB以上でも動作確認できました。迅速なご対応誠にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Spresense Arduino v2.0.0で対応しましたメモリサイズ変更に不具合がありました。
本件につきましては至急修正版をリリースするように致します。

ご不便をお掛けし申し訳ございません。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: ご返事いただき誠にありがとうございます。
修正版のリリースをしていただけるとご返事いただけたこと大変喜ばしく思います。首を長くしてリリースをお待ちしてます。